# javascript плавное изменение положения элемента с паузами

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Блок по клику двигается слева направо, без остановки.

Как сделать чтобы, он останавливался на `500ms` в положении `left=200px` и на `400ms` в положении `left=400px`
сам скрипт для наглядности ниже:

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('.ring').animate({
    left: 800,
  });
});
```

```css
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}
#but {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ring">
</div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="Пуск!">
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```js
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('.ring').animate({
      left: 200,
    }).delay(500)
    .animate({
      left: 400
    }).delay(400)
    .animate({
      left: 800
    });
});
```

```css
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}
#but {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ring">
</div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="Пуск!">
```

Comment: но если к примеру в положении left=300 я захочу сделать чтобы блок кроме того что смещается по оси х еще и сместился по оси y на 200 без остановки такой вариант ведь не подойдет?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, конечно не пойдет, вы же хотели просто остановиться, а не сместиться по оси `y`