# Как сделать анимацию изменения числа от меньшего к большему и обратно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, animate

Eсть переменная, нужно чтобы ее значение возрастало на 40 и возвращалось обратно к исходному, читал, искал, вникал, пока трудно, не получилось ответить на свой вопрос.
Внизу подготовил код, если получится то блок должен зашевелиться по вертикали:

```js
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  w = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  wb = parseInt($('.block').css('height')),
  peremennaya = (h - wb) / 2; //- та переменная, значение которой должно колебаться в пределах 40px

//$(".block").css('top', peremennaya);
$(".block").css('left', (w - wb) / 2);
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

не совсем понял идеи, но, может быть, так:

```js
var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  wb = parseInt($('.block').css('height')),
  tick = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (tick++ >= 80) tick = 0;
  $(".block").css('left', (w - wb) / 2 + Math.abs(tick - 40));
}, 10)
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
```

чтобы меньше дергалось по краям, можно использовать, например, функцию синуса:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  tick++;
  $(".block").css('left', (w - wb) / 2 + Math.sin(tick/100*Math.PI)*40);
}, 10)
```

Comment: Только у Вас среднее берется из clientWidth и css('height'), между шириной и высотой. Я это не стал изменять.

Comment: хотя смущает что не с помощью анимационных эффектов сделано, тут и не задать их. разве что снова математически, очень уж дергается.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, вы уж определитесь - анимационные эффеты, или переменная меняется

Comment: @Grundy плавное изменение числа от одного к другому с помощью анимационных эффектов просто это число будет попадать в переменную а не выводиться в чистом виде на страницу, То есть чтобы можно было задать изменению числа, разные эффекты, возрастающий затухающий линейны и т.д В вопросе подробно описал.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, неа, вообще непонятно :) число это число, если вы меняете его сами - то и эффекты все сами, если вы хотите анимацию, используйте анимацию - в этом случае ваша переменная непонятно куда должна пристраиваться

Comment: @Grundyможно написать анимационный эффект, с помощью которого число будет расти?? 
А можно это вместо начального и конечного числа указать переменную? например тут указано конечно число: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494744/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: в общем мне нужно чтобы блок как в ссылке смещался только не влево, а вверх и вниз, и начальное его положение было переменной

Comment: Непонятно?     ))))))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, а в чем проблема взять пример по ссылке и заменить `left`, на `top`?